# Get product reviews filtered by category

Tags: php, magento, product

How to get product reviews filtered by category?

**I have one category, If i add review in one product and I want to show that review in all the products in that category.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer overwrite this class "Mage_Review_Block_Product_View"

```
class Example_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Review_Block_Product_View {
    public function getReviewsCollection() {
    $category_id = Mage::registry ( 'current_category' )->getId ();
    $category = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/category' )->load ( $category_id );
        $productCollection = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )
                            ->getCollection ()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect ( '*' )
                            ->addCategoryFilter ( $category )
                            ->load ();
        foreach ( $productCollection as $product ) {
            $product_ids [] = $product->getId ();
        }
        if (null === $this->_reviewsCollection) {
    $this->_reviewsCollection = Mage::getModel ( 'review/review' )
                ->getCollection ()
        ->addStoreFilter ( Mage::app ()->getStore ()->getId () )
        ->addStatusFilter ( Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED )
        ->addFieldToFilter ( 'entity_id', Mage_Review_Model_Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT )
                                        ->addFieldToFilter ( 'entity_pk_value', array (
                                                'in' => $product_ids 
                                        ) )->setDateOrder ();
        }

        return $this->_reviewsCollection;
    }
}
```